# Pygame module (I can't import the rect class)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

```
import #pygame
from PYGAME.locals import *
from RECT import *

pygame.init()

#Make Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,240))

#Defining the colors
BLACK = (0,0,0)
GRAY = (127,127,127)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)
MAGENTA = (255, 0, 255)

#Defining a function
def draw_point(text,pos):
    img = font.render(text,True,BLACK)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,RED,pos,3)
    screen.blit(img,pos)
```

**I am unable to import the `RECT` class in the third line.** It's my first time posting a doubt online so thanks for helping out. Due to this, I am unable to define the `draw_point` function.

Comment: `import #pygame` -> `import pygame`. `from RECT import *` -> `from pygame import Rect`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't use `RECT`, so I can only guess at what you're trying to import.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import rect, Rect #one of these is probably what you want
```